# Representing electricity as electrons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, power

Just a thought I had, I was wondering if there was a practical way to do this:

Electricity is represented in Watts per Hour, and obviously, electricity is the flow of electrons.

Is it possible to calculate how many individual electrons have flowed through from point *A* to point *B* in time *t*? What additional information (about the system) do you need to calculate the number of electrons?

Comment: I don't think Watts/Hour is the unit you're looking for. But if you want to think in terms of Coulombs/sec, that might be more doable!

Comment: @JahanClaes The speed of the electrons is not important here. The number of electrons flowing per unit time is solely determined by the current.

Comment: @freecharly You're right, of course. Momentary thoughtlessness. Deleted.

Comment: Watts per hour is not used anywhere for electricity.

Comment: Practical way to do ... what?  What is the task description?   What significance do points A and B have?

Answer (score 1):

You need the current $I$ in A. Current is charge per unit time, i.e. $1A=1Cs^{-1}$. One electron has a charge of $1,602·10^{-19}$ C. Thus a current of $1A$ signifies a flow of $\frac {1}{1,602·10^{-19}}=6.2·10^{18}$ electrons per s.

Comment: Although this is fine in a sense, it doesn't really teach much to anyone.  Would you consider expanding it slightly to include a concept like [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) that adds some depth to the answer ?  E.g. what kind of velocities we're talking about for typical currents in household applications.

Comment: @StephenG The OP asked specifically on the number of electrons flowing and this doesn't depend on any drift velocity, only the total current. Depending on the nature of the current, there even might not exist any drift velocity. Maybe you can give an additional answer expounding the points you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> Electricity is represented in Watts per Hour

Actually, *Quantity of Electricity* is represented in terms of coulombs.  This is the [metric SI definition, MKS units.](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html)  (So, "electricity" means charge, and "flowing electricity" means electric current.)

> and obviously, electricity is the flow of electrons.

No, coulombs are not the flow-rate.

We might say that electricity is the electrons themselves: the flowing electrons are the flowing electricity.  But electricity is also protons, and also is any quantity of charge-carriers.  E.g., the electric current in battery acid is a flow of protons, and electric current in damp dirt and oceans is a flow of mobile ions, the +Na and -Cl, +H and -OH.

To be accurate, the mobile charges *in metals* is the electron-sea or "ocean of charge."  This may be true of metal wires and semiconductors, but does not apply generally.  (And when you get zapped, no electrons flowed through your finger.  People aren't made of copper.)

> Is it possible to calculate how many individual electrons have flowed

Yes, one ampere is a flow-rate of one coulomb per second.   For metal conductors, one coulomb's worth of negative charge-carriers is the inverse of the electronic charge, so one ampere is a flow of 1/1.602e-19 = 6.24e+18 electrons per second.

Weird trivia: the electron density in copper, assuming one free electron per each atom, is 8.5e+22 electrons/cc.  This gives us a physical size of one coulomb of mobile charges: 13600 coulombs/cc, one coulomb forming a cube 0.42mm on a side.   So, inside copper, each coulomb of mobile electricity is like a grain of salt about half a millimeter wide.  And if your wire had similar sectional area, then a one-ampere current would be oozing slowly along at 0.42mm/sec drift rate.  Higher current gives proportionally higher drift velocity.  And for AC, the coulomb just vibrates.

:)